# System of linear equations: get approximate solution with non-negative coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, constraints

I'm looking for a process or algorithm to help me with the following problem. I have the following vectors in $\mathbb R^{3}$:

$$
\vec m_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
51.8\\
2.9\\
22.3
\end{bmatrix},
\vec a = \begin{bmatrix}
20\cr
2\cr
3
\end{bmatrix},
\vec b = \begin{bmatrix}
0.3\\
0\\
6.5
\end{bmatrix},
\vec c = \begin{bmatrix}
20\\
2\\
5
\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to express $\vec m_3$ in terms of the other three. The problem is I need the coefficients to be positive! The solution to this is

$$
\vec m_3 = 240.510\vec a + 76\vec b -238.025\vec c
$$

Given that I need the coefficients to be positive, and I don't care about getting a strictly correct answer (close is good enough), is there an algorithm or process by which I can look for an approximate answer in order to get positive coefficients? The ideal candidate would itself have a parameter for just how relaxed the solution can be.

Currently, I'm thinking a brute force search around $\vec m_3$ in small steps is my only hope :-(

Edit: By close, I mean $\|(x_1\vec a + x_2\vec b + x_3\vec c) - \vec m_3\| \leq \epsilon$

Comment: If you let $A$ be the matrix with $a,b,c$ (or $a,c,w$) as columns, then you could solve the QP $\min \{ \|Ax-m_3\|^2 | x \ge 0 \}$. One could use projected gradients as well.

Comment: To be able to formulate an algorithm, you first need to formalize your notion of *closeness*. You seem to want to minimize $d(\vec{m}_3, x_1\cdot\vec{a}+ x_2\cdot\vec{b},+x_3\cdot\vec{c})$ according to *some* distance function $d$, but you didn't specify how that distance is defined.. A possible choice would be $d(u,v) = \|u-v\|$, i.e. the euclidean distance, but there are other options. (And btw, your notation seems to be inconsistent. In the first equation, the vectors are $\vec{a}$,$\vec{c}$, $\vec{w}$, but in the second they are $\vec{a}$,$\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$)

Comment: I've updated the variables - thank you. As for the distance, euclidean distance would be fine for now. I am intrigued at the idea of varying ideas of closeness however, as one of these dimensions is "more important" than the others given the real-world implications.

Comment: @copper.hat - I'm currently looking at what matrix gradients are and their uses. Thanks - any additional "keywords" fitting this problem that I can research are appreciated.

Comment: A keyword is non negative least squares. Matlab has a function for that.  You minimize the norm of the residual subject to a non negativity constraint. This optimization problem could be solved using proximal algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nonnegative least squares problem is to minimize the norm of the residual $ Ax -b $ subject to the constraint that the components of $ x $ are nonnegative. This optimization problem could be solved using proximal algorithms, such as the projected gradient method. Matlab has a function that will solve this problem for you.

Comment: Also, scipy.optimize.nnls - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html 
Thanks for the answer! I needed to know that this was an 'optimization problem', specifically a non-negative least squares problem - as you mentioned.

Comment: It would also be possible to minimize the $1$-norm of the residual, or the $\infty $ norm, if that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the greedy method.

Find the largest u such that
$m_a = m-u\ a$ has all non-negative components.

Then find the largest v such that
$m_b = m_a-v\ b$ has all non-negative components.

Finally, find the largest w such that
$m_c = m_b-w\ c$ has all non-negative components.

The approximation is then
$ua+vb+wc$.

I have no idea how good
the resulting approximation will be.
I only know that
the coefficients will be
non-negative.